# Angular - creating html elements with a function inside ngFor are not displayed correctly

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to make a reusable component in Angular 10. Here's my html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let element of elements">
       {{ createHtmlElement(element) }}
    </div>
</form>
```

and the function called is

```
createHtmlElement(element): HTMLElement {
    if (element.input) {
      const input = document.createElement("input")
      input.type = element.type;
      input.id = element.id;
      input.className = 'form-control';
      input['formControlName'] = element.id;
      return input;
    }
}
```

but what i get on screen is this

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

is there an Angular feature that allows me to do this properly?

Comment: You can do it with renderer but there is a better way to do it. Can you share `adding properties`

Comment: sure, edited. there is more to the function, it's just similar code for creating select etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has a feature which allow property binding on template.

You can bind attributes on template like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let element of elements">
       <input [type]="element.type" [id]="element.id" class="form-control" [formControlName]="element.id" />
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks, this is actually one of the first things one learns with angular, i tripped myself by overcomplicating the solution